# python - how to append n csv files preserving the column order

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**How to append n csv files preserving column order?**

Column headers might differ in each file, so that some columns might be missing or some new columns might be appearing in the consecutive files.

**For example**

```
File1
Column2 Column1 Column4
1       1       Text1
1       1       Text1

File2
Column2 Column1 Column3 Column4 Column5
2         2        2    Text2   xxx
2         2        2    Text2   xxx

File3
Column2 Column1 Column3 Column4
3              3    3   Text3
3              3    3   Text3
```

**Desired Output**

```
Column2 Column1 Column4 Column3 Column5
1          1    Text1
1          1    Text1
2          2    Text2       2     xxx
2          2    Text2       2     xxx
3          3    Text3       3
3          3    Text3       3
```

I am trying to use pandas but the columns in the final output get sorted alphabetically.
**Is there any way to avoid the alphabetical sorting / control the column order?**

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob("C:\CSVs\*.csv")
df_list = []

for filename in sorted(files):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
full_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index= True)

full_df.to_csv('output3.csv')
```

I am getting

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5
...
```

Comment: Assuming that `full_df` is the name of the final dataframe you can re-order the columns using `full_df = full_df[['Column2', 'Column1', 'Column4', 'Column3', 'Column5']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way out, it will work dynamically according to the header of files:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob("./CSVs/*.csv")
df_list = []
col_list=[]
for filename in sorted(files):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_list.append(df)
    for e in list(df.columns):
        if e not in new_col_list:
            col_list.append(e)
full_df = pd.concat(df_list)
full_df = full_df[col_list]
full_df
```

Output:

```
    Column2 Column1 Column4 Column3 Column5
0   1       1       Text1   NaN     NaN
1   1       1       Text1   NaN     NaN
0   2       2       Text2   2       xxx
1   2       2       Text2   2       xxx
0   3       3       Text3   3       NaN
1   3       3       Text3   3       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import itertools

files = glob.glob("C:\CSVs\*.csv")
df_list = []
new_col_list = []
for filename in sorted(files):
    x = pd.read_csv(filename)
    df_list.append(x)
    new_col_list.append(x.columns)
full_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index= True)
new_col_list_merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(new_col_list))
full_df_updated = full_df[new_col_list_merged ]
full_df.to_csv('output3.csv')
```

Hope this should work

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the final column order, you can try this:

```
full_df = full_df.reindex_axis(['Column2', 'Column1', 'Column4', 'Column3', 'Column5'], axis=1)
full_df.to_csv('output3.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> df = file1.append(file2).append(file3)
>>> df.reset_index(inplace=True)

>>> df.reindex(columns=['Column2', 'Column1', 'Column4', 'Column3', 'Column5'])
   Column2  Column1 Column4  Column3 Column5
0        1        1   Text1      NaN     NaN
1        1        1   Text1      NaN     NaN
2        2        2   Text2      2.0     xxx
3        2        2   Text2      2.0     xxx
4        3        3   Text3      3.0     NaN
5        3        3   Text3      3.0     NaN
```